# Encoding error in TopoJSON module

Tags: node.js, geojson, topojson

I'm having this error, and I just don't know if it's an issue or something I'm doing wrong. When converting a GeoJSON file, generated by

`ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" INPUT.json INPUT.shp`

with the topojson module, and preserving the properties, some Spanish characters are not preserved:

`topojson -p -o OUTPUT.json INPUT.json`

For example: `Castellón` from the INPUT.json file (checked, there are  no erros in that file) ends like `Castell�n` in the OUTPUT.json file. The properties are well preserved except for characters like `á`, `í`, `ó`, etc. (common in Spanish).

I've tried adding `--shapefile-encoding utf8` without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's almost 1 year late but I'll lleave here my solution because probably more people will have this problem.
Solved it in 2 steps:

1. In the conversion from shp to geojson I encoded it as UTF-8 instead of the standard ISO 8859-1 (I used QGIS for this instead of command line ogr2ogr)
2. In topojson I added the option `--shapefile-encoding utf8` as Nacho did

And all my beautiful accents and tildes are back